# How to remove the cells or like to get a report in centre of the page in XLS format

Tags: jasper-reports, export-to-excel

I have done a report using jasper reports and got the report very well but my concern is when i open the report its opening in XLS format but it is going entirely to left part of the page,as shown below[image]

I want report to be centre of the page and all the extra cells like 'M','N','O' are to be removed.

Report.jsp

```
<body>

<%
String sql=null;
Connection conn = null;
try 
{
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/marketing_database","root","root");
    sql = "select company_profile.companyName AS 'cname',quotationclient_details.RefNo,quotationclient_details.Date,quotationclient_details.CustomerName,quotationclient_details.CompanyName AS 'ccname',quotationclient_details.PaymentTerm,quotationclient_details.DeliveryTime,quotationclient_details.Validity,quotation.Item,quotation.id,quotation.Description,quotation.Quantity,quotation.PerUnitPrice,quotation.TotalPrice,quotation.VAT5,quotation.VAT14,quotation.CST,quotationclient_details.MobileNo,quotation.ServiceTax,company_profile.companyLogo,company_profile.companyLetterHead from quotation,quotationclient_details,company_profile where quotation.CId In (select max(CId) from quotationclient_details) and quotationclient_details.CId In (select max(CId) from quotationclient_details)";
    ServletContext context = request.getServletContext(); 
    String fullPath = context.getRealPath("/WEB-INF/reports/report9.jrxml");
    InputStream input = new FileInputStream(new File(fullPath));
    JasperDesign jasperDesign = JRXmlLoader.load(input);

    System.out.println("Compiling Report Designs");
    JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jasperDesign);

    System.out.println("Creating JasperPrint Object");
    HashMap<String,Object> map = new HashMap<String,Object>();
    map.put("sql",sql);
    JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport (jasperReport,map,conn); 
    byte bytes[] = new byte[10000]; 
    //String result = JasperRunManager.runReportToHtmlFile("./usertemplates/test.jasper" , parameters, conn); 



    JRXlsExporter exporter = new JRXlsExporter(); 
    ByteArrayOutputStream xlsReport = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); 
    exporter.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jasperPrint);
    exporter.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_WHITE_PAGE_BACKGROUND,Boolean.TRUE);
    exporter.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_DETECT_CELL_TYPE, Boolean.TRUE); 
    exporter.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_REMOVE_EMPTY_SPACE_BETWEEN_ROWS,Boolean.TRUE);
    exporter.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_REMOVE_EMPTY_SPACE_BETWEEN_COLUMNS,Boolean.TRUE);
    exporter.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IGNORE_PAGE_MARGINS,Boolean.TRUE);
    exporter.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_ONE_PAGE_PER_SHEET,Boolean.TRUE);
    exporter.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM, xlsReport); 
    exporter.exportReport(); 
    //System.out.println("Size of byte array:"+xlsReport.size()); 
    //bytes = xlsReport.toByteArray();
    String fileName = "QuotationReport.xls";
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename="
+ fileName);
    response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel"); 
    //System.out.println("After JasperPrint = 1"); 
    response.setContentLength(xlsReport.size()); 
    //System.out.println("After JasperPrint = 2"); 
    //xlsReport.close(); 
    //System.out.println("After JasperPrint = 3"); 

    OutputStream outputStream = response.getOutputStream(); 
    System.out.println("After JasperPrint = 4"); 
    xlsReport.writeTo(outputStream); 
    outputStream.flush(); 
    //outputStream.close(); 
    } 
    catch(Exception e) 
    {e.printStackTrace();} 

        %>
</body>
```

report.jrxml

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="report11" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" scriptletClass="com.reporter.jasper.ConvertToWord" uuid="16229028-8f93-4195-966f-09e0c49feb94">
            <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
            <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
            <property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
            <queryString>
                <![CDATA[select
        company_profile.companyName AS 'cname',
        quotationclient_details.RefNo,
        quotationclient_details.Date,
        quotationclient_details.CustomerName,
        quotationclient_details.CompanyName AS 'ccname',
        quotationclient_details.PaymentTerm,
        quotationclient_details.DeliveryTime,
        quotationclient_details.Validity,
        quotation.Item,quotation.id,
        quotation.Description,
        quotation.Quantity,
        quotation.PerUnitPrice,
        quotation.TotalPrice,
        quotation.VAT5,
        quotation.VAT14,
        quotation.CST,
        quotationclient_details.MobileNo,
        quotation.ServiceTax,
        company_profile.companyLogo,
        company_profile.companyLetterHead
        from quotation,quotationclient_details,company_profile where quotation.CId In (select max(CId) from quotationclient_details) and quotationclient_details.CId In (select max(CId) from quotationclient_details)]]>
            </queryString>
            <field name="cname" class="java.lang.String"/>
            <field name="RefNo" class="java.lang.String">
                <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
            </field>
            <field name="Date" class="java.sql.Date">
                <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
            </field>
            <field name="CustomerName" class="java.lang.String">
                <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
            </field>
            <field name="ccname" class="java.lang.String"/>
            <field name="PaymentTerm" class="java.lang.String">
                <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
            </field>
            <field name="DeliveryTime" class="java.lang.String">
                <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
            </field>
            <field name="Validity" class="java.lang.String">
                <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
            </field>
            <field name="Item" class="java.lang.String">
                <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
            </field>
            <field name="id" class="java.lang.Long">
                <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
            </field>
            <field name="Description" class="java.lang.String">
                <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
            </field>
            <field name="Quantity" class="java.lang.Long">
                <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
            </field>
            <field name="PerUnitPrice" class="java.lang.Double">
                <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
            </field>
            <field name="TotalPrice" class="java.lang.Double">
                <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
            </field>
            <field name="VAT5" class="java.lang.Float">
                <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
            </field>
            <field name="VAT14" class="java.lang.Float">
                <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
            </field>
            <field name="CST" class="java.lang.Float">
                <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
            </field>
            <field name="MobileNo" class="java.lang.String">
                <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
            </field>
            <field name="ServiceTax" class="java.lang.Float">
                <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
            </field>
            <field name="companyLogo" class="java.sql.Blob">
                <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
            </field>
            <field name="companyLetterHead" class="java.sql.Blob">
                <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
            </field>
            <variable name="Sub Total" class="java.lang.Integer" calculation="Sum">
                <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{TotalPrice}]]></variableExpression>
            </variable>
            <variable name="Output VAT and CST and Service Tax" class="java.lang.Integer" calculation="Sum">
                <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{VAT5} +$F{VAT14} +$F{ServiceTax} +$F{CST}]]></variableExpression>
            </variable>
            <title>
                <band height="260" splitType="Stretch">
                    <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                        <reportElement x="25" y="102" width="268" height="20" uuid="f2e6a64d-e30b-4b5d-8ce0-8aa347bf4b24"/>
                        <box>
                            <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                            <leftPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
                            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        </box>
                        <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                            <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="9" pdfFontName="Times-Roman" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
                        </textElement>
                        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{RefNo}]]></textFieldExpression>
                    </textField>
                    <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" pattern="">
                        <reportElement x="293" y="102" width="262" height="20" uuid="3fbe0992-ece7-424f-b6e7-100482dcb771"/>
                        <box>
                            <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                            <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        </box>
                        <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                            <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="9" pdfFontName="Times-Roman" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
                        </textElement>
                        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{Date}]]></textFieldExpression>
                    </textField>
                    <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                        <reportElement x="313" y="122" width="242" height="14" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="91ce3cf8-5ab5-45f1-97ac-92b88d453158"/>
                        <box>
                            <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        </box>
                        <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                            <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="9" pdfFontName="Times-Roman" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
                        </textElement>
                        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{CustomerName}]]></textFieldExpression>
                    </textField>
                    <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                        <reportElement x="313" y="136" width="242" height="13" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="8917fe3e-5ff5-492d-82c4-441701f82f7e"/>
                        <box>
                            <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        </box>
                        <textElement>
                            <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="9" pdfFontName="Times-Roman" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
                        </textElement>
                        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{ccname}]]></textFieldExpression>
                    </textField>
                    <staticText>
                        <reportElement x="313" y="149" width="242" height="13" uuid="246061b8-09fd-4086-a735-146048a7a201"/>
                        <box>
                            <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        </box>
                        <textElement markup="none">
                            <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="9" pdfFontName="Times-Roman" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
                        </textElement>
                        <text><![CDATA[]]></text>
                    </staticText>
                    <textField>
                        <reportElement x="313" y="175" width="242" height="20" uuid="c299b4ca-f46e-49ca-8d4f-b3204d06fc89"/>
                        <box>
                            <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        </box>
                        <textElement markup="none">
                            <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="9" pdfFontName="Times-Roman" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
                        </textElement>
                        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{MobileNo}]]></textFieldExpression>
                    </textField>
    <staticText>
                    <reportElement x="0" y="195" width="555" height="20" forecolor="#FF0000" uuid="cc2007f5-62a9-4b1c-a204-09566e931526"/>
                    <box>
                        <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    </box>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                        <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="10" pdfFontName="Times-Roman" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <text><![CDATA[Sub Quotation for supply of UPS and Batteries]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement x="10" y="215" width="545" height="45" uuid="3ae6bde4-be3c-40f0-8ac7-ac1274007b22"/>
                    <box>
                        <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <leftPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
                        <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    </box>
                    <textElement>
                        <font fontName="Times New Roman" pdfFontName="Times-Roman" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <text><![CDATA[Dear Sir,
    We thank you for your enquiry and the interest shown in our range of products and services.As per the requirements provided by you,please find here below our revised offer in INR for the same]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement x="0" y="122" width="293" height="14" uuid="509840bf-7159-427d-93ff-e4cf88dc48aa"/>
                    <box>
                        <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    </box>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Right">
                        <font fontName="Times New Roman" pdfFontName="Times-Roman"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <text><![CDATA[Contact Person Name:]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement x="0" y="136" width="293" height="13" uuid="6a696a9c-830d-46de-9124-f1a5344c30d3"/>
                    <box>
                        <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    </box>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Right">
                        <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="10" pdfFontName="Times-Roman" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <text><![CDATA[Company Name:]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement x="0" y="149" width="293" height="13" uuid="b9000080-e944-4e1f-a711-378e36c247b5"/>
                    <box>
                        <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    </box>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Right">
                        <font fontName="Times New Roman" pdfFontName="Times-Roman" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <text><![CDATA[Address:]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement x="0" y="162" width="293" height="13" uuid="9f8b1f79-c8fd-4a65-9f93-4ce48440045b"/>
                    <box>
                        <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    </box>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Right">
                        <font fontName="Times New Roman" pdfFontName="Times-Roman" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <text><![CDATA[Email:]]></text>
                </staticText>
<staticText>
                <reportElement x="313" y="162" width="242" height="13" uuid="1eac5333-e70c-4afe-89bc-3fb39a8c9bef"/>
                <box>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                </box>
                <textElement markup="none">
                    <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="9" pdfFontName="Times-Roman" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="175" width="293" height="20" uuid="7ecaa5cb-f93c-49b6-89a0-1a211c4447fc"/>
                <box>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right">
                    <font fontName="Times New Roman" pdfFontName="Times-Roman" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Mobile Number:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="102" width="25" height="20" uuid="2981d3cf-d5f5-476b-b0db-9f76aa3be7e6"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                </box>
                <textElement>
                    <font pdfFontName="Times-Roman" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="555" height="10" uuid="0da2ed25-3390-41fb-b11c-4a7255b8ffc2"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                </box>
                <textElement>
                    <font pdfFontName="Times-Roman" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="215" width="10" height="45" uuid="67f718dd-bc9f-45a1-9672-86ccb888b94f"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                </box>
                <text><![CDATA[]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <image>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="0" y="10" width="139" height="92" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="bc88f358-7651-47e5-9569-8860c0a0257a">
                    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.auto.fit.row" value="false"/>
                    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.auto.fit.column" value="true"/>
                </reportElement>
                <box>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                </box>
                <imageExpression><![CDATA[$F{companyLogo}.getBinaryStream()]]></imageExpression>
            </image>
```

Comment: @PetterFriberg No i didnt tried this one.I asked this question because i thought i need this in excel,but in future i think i need this and i wanted to test it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *"all the extra cells like 'M','N','O' are to be removed?"*

Cells can **not** be removed in excel (as far as I know), you can hide them but then you will see 'P', 'Q','S' since this is how excel was developed.

> *"I want report to be center of the page"* (interpreted as printed on center, otherwise again it depends only on the dimension of the excel window)

**Using margins (the easy way)**

remove
`exporter.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IGNORE_PAGE_MARGINS,Boolean.TRUE);` and set the margins as you like them.

**Using excel function in print >> margins: Center the worksheet horizontally on page**

I have not found any property in jasper report to achieve this, but using directly [POI](https://poi.apache.org/) it fairly simple (note you already have this library in your class path, jasper report use it to export to excel)

To do this you need first to export the report es. to a file (on server) or if you have memory to a `ByteArray`, this example presumes that you have export it to a `File excelFile` on your server

```
HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream(excelFile)); //create the workbook with POI
int ns = workbook.getNumberOfSheets();//Get the number of sheets (margins is set on sheet not on woorkbook
for (int i = 0; i < ns; i++) {
  HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(i); //Get the sheet
  sheet.setHorizontallyCenter(true); //Set the property
  //sheet.setMargin(Sheet.LeftMargin, 0.5);//You can also set margins ecc here margins are in Inches
}
workbook.write(outputStream); //write the excel to your stream
workbook.close(); //And close it
```